# Java 17 and LDAP - superclass access check failed

Tags: java, exception, ldap

We're using some old Java code to access an LDAP directory and we're moving to Java 17 now. We're getting an exception:

```
superclass access check failed: class com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.PagedResultsControl (in unnamed module @0x11614aef) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.BasicControl (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x11614aef
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.PagedResultsControl (in unnamed module @0x11614aef) cannot access class com.sun.jndi.ldap.BasicControl (in module java.naming) because module java.naming does not export com.sun.jndi.ldap to unnamed module @0x11614aef
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
```

I can add --add-opens java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED to the startup options and it seems to work. However, I'd like to change the code, I don't like to use this option.

Now I'm a bit lost in this Java Modules thing. Must I change our code to use modules? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It looks like you have code using JDK internal class, and would need to show the code.

Comment: `com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.PagedResultsControl` is not included in JDK 17, you can find it in  ldapbp (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/ldapbp/1.0) or (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.ldapbp/ldapbp/7.0.3)

Comment: Based on the name, are you sure you shouldn't be using `javax.naming.ldap.PagedResultsControl` instead?

Comment: @life888888 Based on the exception, as it is in the unnamed module, it seems the OP is using a separate library which contains `com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.PagedResultsControl`, which then attempts to load `com.sun.jndi.ldap.BasicControl`, which does exist in Java 17, in the module `java.naming`, but it is not exported.